What does the community want to do with identification questions?
There have been several topics and discussions about whether "identification questions" should be on-topic or off-topic. Now, anytime such a question is asked, pros and cons come with their arguments. But I feel like that's nowhere close to being resolved, as it goes on and on again, and related topics are many years old.
Is it time to discuss this again?
Will we reach a consensus?
Time (and answers, upvotes, downvotes) will tell...
Related topics:

https://stackoverflow.blog/2012/02/29/lets-play-the-guessing-game/ (2012)
Discussion on identification questions (2012)
What can we do with generic "NAME THIS MOVIE" question titles? (2015)
Shall we ban identification questions? (2016)
Check in on Identification questions (2017)
We are discontinuing support for identification questions (2018)
Why are ID questions banned when there are only 55 votes in favor of it and 135 votes against it? (2024)


Finally some has the guts to actually come out and ask it. So first and foremost thank you for the intiative! However, as we've seen time and time again on SE, simple polls on one liners aren't really going to resolve anything. I'd encourage anyone be they pro or con ID or anything in between, to properly present their arguments or plans forward in an effort for the comprehensive discussion this serious issue deserves. I'd remove the answer stubs for now and let people present some proper answers to discuss.

We should probably narrow the focus to identify what? Just movies? Music in movies,  actors? ...and what clues/information bases are acceptable? Just images? Plot/scene descriptions., Youtube clips etc. (remembering that images and YT are not indexable.

A simple up/down yes/no vote seems the most sensible way to proceed.

Frankly, my main concern isn't that we're going to win or lose the vote. Regardless of how we proceed, the existing moderator team have made it clear that they hate these questions with a vengeance and are going to act with bad faith to undermine the result, then ultimately delete the product of people's efforts.

@Valorum Frankly, Valorum, if you're going to throw accusations like these around, I'd be careful with attributing bad faith to others if I was known across SE for gaslighting people into thinking your interpretation of site policy is the one true reality. Stuff like that really isn't going to get us foward. We have discussion going now. If you don't want to actually discuss the issue rather than pointing at a number and say "look, people asking ID question like ID questions", then continue that but don't pretend it's the only thing you can do.

@NapoleonWilson - This isn't an "accusation", it's a precise description of what happened in 2016, where there was a successful vote to preserve them that was then reversed in 2017 under dubious circumstances. People's ID questions and answers, representing thousands of hours of effort, were then destroyed utterly. I fail to see any reason we shouldn't assume that will happen again.

@Valorum: I give credit to people first. So, I'll see what they think/say (if they do) and how they behave. But innocent until proven guilty :)

If you believe it or not, I'd be happy with a clear outcome from this discussion, no matter what that outcome is. However, things simply aren't as clear as a vote score on an announcement post, the last 14 years have shown that. I'm sure you like to pretend they are. But for now I'd like us to focus on finally discussing this issue without continuous underhanded pseudo posts beating around the bush of if we want these questions or not. More than 6 years ago we decided we don't, maybe things have changed, maybe they haven't.

I still have a strong opinion about these questions based on their value and what I think they will ultimately do to the site and I will probably try to make that heard in time. But I'm also not worried enough about them to die on that hill and drag the site into the grave with me if those qiestions are genuinely what the community wants. But we'll also not revise an established and successful policy simply because two users like them and point at the score of a 6 year old announcement. You think they deserve another chance, then finally put in the work for once and make a case for them.

@NapoleonWilson "Finally put in the work for once and make a case for them"  Isn't that what some of these users have been doing already?  This is the reason that I had to take a break from this site.  I was making a case and nobody was listening.  What else do you want them to do? lol.  You're a mod.  Create a Meta post with a yes/no voting system and ask the community what they want.  Boom.

@steelersquirrel We have a meta discussion now and are all concerning ourselves with this issue. People leaving angry comments or complaining in chat isn't the sme as genuine discussion for revisiting a long standing policy. All that ever happened is a few users beating around the bush with side questions. If we want ID back, let's actually talk about that. Maybe we should have started this discussion earlier, when seeing this unrest from a select few users, I give you that. But we have it now and we can actually talk about the issue instead of merely pointing at votes.

@NapoleonWilson That's all fine and good to have a discussion; however, the discussion aspect is why we are here again.  These users (myself included) want to see a community vote rather than a discussion.  Y'all keep saying that ID was banned because of "discussions" rather than community votes.  I just don't want to see that happen again here.  Just let the community vote to bring them back

"Let the community vote to bring them back" - I like how you put that. ;-) I know some people wish it was that easy  But the "trouble with popularity" is why this issue is still a problem 14 years later. Sometimes things actually need to be talked about. That is what meta is for. If policy were merely a poll, we wouldn't need a meta site.

Okay...fine.  I'll rephrase "Let the community vote if they want to bring them back" lol.  If policy were merely a poll, then why did you guys put up the meta vote to ban them?

You mean that old one? Well, we all have to learn how things work. ;-) SE themselves were quite clear back then on how this was a bad approach to the problem.

Do we really need another meta post on the topic of identification questions? I believe the community's consensus on this issue is already clear from the previous three meta discussions and the voting results on their answers: Shall we ban identification questions?, Check in on Identification questions, and We are discontinuing support for identification questions.

… Notably, despite the pro-ID ban stance in these meta posts, the top-voted answers are clearly against banning such questions.

I know you think that and I understand from your point of view (or at least the one you claim to have) there isn't much to convince you of the opposite. However, I'm genuinely happy that the Old Padawan has, himself a concerned community member, finally started a discussion based on an unrest he himself observed in the community. Much like DForck42's question back then, the moderators didn't actually need to stickle him on behind the scenes to ask this. So I honestly would want us all to concentrate on making this a productive discussion about the future of ID questions on this site.

As a general closing-remark (although hopes aren't too high it actually "closes" anything ;-)) and not adressing anyone in particular, now would be a very good time to show that what you are after isn't merely moderation drama rather than that you genuinely care about making this site and the internet a better place and why you think identification questions do actually contribute to that.

"the moderators didn't actually need to stickle him on behind the scenes to ask this." (him being me, the writer of this): I can confirm that I never ever had direct interaction with any staff member or moderator of this stack. I initiated the above discussion because there were multiple comments on the main site, and I was kind of fed up with this 'no give no take but pull the rope'... Still am though :)

What are everyone's thoughts on updating the note in the "support for identification questions" meta post to reflect our ongoing policy discussion?

@NapoleonWilson You: "So I honestly would want us all to concentrate on making this a productive discussion about the future of ID questions on this site" Also you: "Finally some has the guts to actually come out and ask it." The latter quote seems to be a comment on the character of others who did not "come out and ask it", which is not a comment that is aligned with the former quote.

@ToddWilcox: I can understand that many users didn't want to open what might be a Pandora's box. Doing so, I hope I didn't harm the community by pouring oil on fire, just did what I thought was right. It doesn't mean others are gutless :)

@ToddWilcox: just to 'bring more water to the mill' (instead of just pulling the rope :)) -> I wonder how that question (amongst others) can get 40+ UV and 1. be self-answered 2. get 2 bad answers 3. 1 answer with as many UV as DV (3-3) despite being awfully wrong (see1st comment). That's exactly why I'm fed up with this not-so-productive discussion (the one I opened, yup...) and others before, and why I still think these IDQs are so useless VLQC (Very Low Quality Crap).

@OldPadawan Aren’t there non-ID questions with similar characteristics? Either way those scores are high, which suggests people like ID questions. This is why I was curious if SE sites are really democracies, because it seems like most people are pro-ID.

@ToddWilcox They never have been... Moderators are appointed for "life" and are only ever removed under community revolt or extenuating circumstances.. BUT that is a whole other conversation (and has been happening on main meta as well).

@Skooba Yeah I know. I was curious. That's why I asked this question and learned afterwards that it's not about votes and self answered: https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5030/why-are-id-questions-banned-when-there-are-only-55-votes-in-favor-of-it-and-135

Since the community consensus is now clear, I've now requested the moderators implement the change in site policy: Please update the site policy to reflect community consensus on allowing identification questions

Regardless of the rest of the content of the discussion, accusing Valorum of gaslighting was in my opinion utterly unjustified. An extraordinary accusation like that requires extraordinary evidence, and I have certainly witnessed no such misconduct from them (sorry @Valorum, I don't know your pronouns!) in my time on SFF.SE.

This appears to be the latest Meta post, but on the main site adding an id question flashes up an 'id questions are not allowed. Though about half the first page of posts are ID questions. So what's what?

@Jontia "on the main site adding an id question flashes up an 'id questions are not allowed." I can't seem to reproduce that issue. Could you provide more details on how it happens? If you could start a meta post about it, that’d help us investigate.

@galacticninja I can't reproduce it now either. It was a warning message saying ID questions are not excepted, similar to the one you get if you forget to include a title. But it hasn't come up this time around.

NO modification, keep ID questions off-topic. I'd like that policy to remain as is, a minima for the title of the movie. Here are my points:
I think this policy, despite being perceived as harsh and constraining, is the one that this community needs. Why? Because, having seen how it works for years, my opinion is that identification questions lower the quality level of this stack.
Of course, these questions attract new users and generate some traffic, but these persons, for most of them, won't stay after they get their answer and never contribute again. And we're stuck with one question and answer(s) that will benefit one person only. That is not what SE should be about, what it was built for, a library of knowledge, intended for the many.
Beside that, low quality questions ask for much more work than the average question.  I can only rank these as "gimme th3 c0d3" type of question on SO. They're different in essence, but the spirit is the same: I don't know, so feed me with the answer I need, and ciao bambino!
Identification questions are no more than a fun trivia, like the one you can play with family and friends. "Guess who?". "Pict it". And others I don't know. Fun for a while, but not that much.
I know users can set their homepage to ignore the identification tag, but many don't even know that, and I'm pretty sure the vast majority of visitors will see a homepage filled with many ID questions, misleading them about the core of this stack. Closing your eyes doesn't make the dirt disappear, it hides it for you, but the stains are still here, and the others can still see it.
ID questions are low-quality items, badly written most of the time, and degrade the overall quality of the stack. They're bad apples that will stain the basket.
There are some other points that can be discussed, such as music, because it can be likened to props, and be an important part of the movie? But then, it would depend on the importance, on the relation to the narration...etc
As stated by Jeff Atwood in his blog post Let's Play The Guessing Game:

The question owner tries to describe something they can't quite remember, in hopes that the greater community will "buzz in" to hazard an answer based on the limited information provided, like on a game show. The best guess gets upvotes, and potentially an accepted answer checkmark. It's fun, right?
Of course, guessing game questions aren't a new phenomenon; I alluded to them in the Pee-Wee Herman Rule. But after a year of observing these guessing game questions grow and spread to multiple sites with similar effects, I no longer believe that the slight benefit of these questions outweighs the many negatives.

When people say that the rules of a stack should be modified because a majority of users wants to, is it potentially a sense of democracy or a coup d'état? If tomorrow I find myself regrouped with many people who want the right to curse all throughout the posts and insult others, just because I get loads of upvotes, do we need to allow this?
Just because a post is upvoted, an another one downvoted, then the winner is... ? Is that really the kind of childish decision our community needs for such an important matter? Based on a poll? Shouldn't we look at the greater picture, and still aim for excellence instead of some "instant (kind of) trivia fun"?
If people want to change the established rules, it has to be for the greater good of many, not just the few dozen (at best) willing to. New blood? Maybe. What about the old blood? Too old, so get rid of it? Many users may have left when ID questions got cut, but many users will probably also leave if this stack is flooded with low quality posts.

"these questions attract new users and generate some traffic" - Movies:SE site traffic is at an all-time low, and significantly lower than the point at which the site left beta. Perhaps attracting some new blood isn't such a bad idea.

"Perhaps attracting some new blood isn't such a bad idea.": in my opinion, it's a clear no. Not at all costs. "Keep it high or let it die" is a motto that led me through life in all I did. It forced me (and still does) to always try and do my best. I'm never selling my values for any (cheap) 'revenue'. And that would be somehow the case here...

Rule of acquisition #109 would apply here

@Valorum: it's probably easier to trade something you ignore the value of because you never possessed it, but I cherish mine so... thanks, but, no thanks. Rule #19 would probably apply here.

That to me has been the problem all along. There has very much been a "to save the village we had to destroy the village" mentality. Having excluded a popular class of questions, resulting in several of the sites top members leaving, and devastating site-engagement levels, the winners sat back and congratulated themselves on having fixed the site.

@Valorum: I'm possibily wrong, and willing to accept it, but please write an email to Jeff Atwood explaining how his vision is biased and how he built his village on unsteady foundations. And share the answer with us. Or write your own. I personally share his vision.

"Many users may have left when ID questions got cut, but many users will probably also leave if this stack is flooded with low quality posts." - And many users might already have left because we didn't do anything against ID until '18. It's ultimately hard to count which group is larger or would have brought more fruitful site contributions. Users come and go over all those years.

@OldPadawan Jeff Atwood hasn't been involved in SE decision-making for a decade now. Back when he was, he was known for provocative comments (e.g. "the correct answer to any question at SFF.SE is 'who cares'") and alienating entire communities. I'm sure he also made a lot of good points which are worth arguing for on their merits, but "please write an email to Jeff Atwood" is unhelpfully dismissive and irrelevant to discussing SE policy in 2024.

@Randal'Thor: the then policy, even that old, shall stay as is (in my opinion). My recommandation of writing an email was merely a humoristic 2nd degree attempt at saying "I like his points and arguments." I hope he probably hasn't changed his mind though. But his 12 years old arguments still seem good nowadays.

@OldPadawan I have yet to see clear, current evidence of community support for the ID ban policy. Close reasons should have something to point to (usually a meta post, not a Jeff Atwood blog post) as evidence of community support for a close reason.

@galacticninja : "Close reasons should have something to point to (a meta post...)..." -> this can be collectively written I believe.

@galacticninja I actually agree with you - there is no clear current evidence of community support.  The response to this post however is that there isn't much evidence for anything, either support for the ban or support to overturn it.

One can either work out how to obtain such evidence, or decide whether overturning an existing policy based on little evidence, or maintaining a policy based on little support is the worse evil.

"whether overturning an existing policy based on little evidence, or maintaining a policy based on little support is the worse evil.": you're so d*** right sir! :) There will be (un)happy people no matter what anyway...

"these persons won't stay after they get their answer and never contribute again" Is there any analysis we can do to establish whether this is actually true?

@ToddWilcox: trying to find that data on SO where I saw it once, years ago, about new users who wouldn't interact again after a massive DV on LQQ, closed-question or right after an answer (1 question / 1 answer / never return). Couln't write the proper request on SEDE either to extract that kind of data, if possible anyway (this, I don't know)

@OldPadawan I recall seeing something like that buried in one of our old ID debates. I don't believe it will be possible to reproduce it now since those questions have been deleted from the database. Not sure if that would affect the old results in the discussion, depends on how it was linked.

Probably this - Statistics on identification questions and their askers

@Paulie_D - Interesting stuff. Almost 33% of ID askers hung around and did more things on the site. By removing these 3000+ questions, the site basically sacrificed nearly 1000 users who would have asked a second question. Those are users that we could desperately be doing with now.

@Valorum: I actually read numbers a little differently. I see that we would need to keep 66% of crap to get 33% of new users. Because in order to have them stay, we'd need to deal with and keep all of the IDQs. I don't read that as 'worth it'.

@OldPadawan - Sure, but it's pretty clear that removing their questions is going to drive them away. That's all fine and dandy when we have users to burn, but that ain't the case at the moment. The site is dying on its arse and banning ID questions is merely hastening the demise. A better solution might be to engage with ID-question-askers and encourage them to ask a non-ID question to follow up

@Valorum: my only ideas at the moment would be to 1. help them in chat (eventually give them the answer there) and encourage them to post again? 2. create a meta post with a short notice about it, and answer them there (but very very bad option in my opinion). 3. someone who come with a good idea :)

@OldPadawan Consider the saying "You miss 100% of the shots you don't take." A 33% retention rate means we're gaining one active user for every 3 users who asked an ID question as their first question. Sure, it's not perfect, but it's a lot better than shutting the door completely and missing out on all those potential contributors. With the site feeling like a ghost town lately, shouldn't we at least consider ways to attract new users?

@OldPadawan - My ideas are 1) Help them by answering their question and make them feel welcome on the site and 2) Stop repeatedly being rude to them so that they leave.

@galacticninja - Plus the new tools allow those who are annoyed by ID question to just ignore them.

@Valorum "A better solution might be to engage with ID-question-askers and encourage them to ask a non-ID question to follow up" - That is actually a good and laudable approach indeed. It is the first move away from all this "I just want them to post their question" towards an acual way forward of how to make these questions work. However your two ideas don't seem to do anything like that. They might be a start, but they alone do nothing of the sort to deal with the problems that OldPadawan lines out.

@NapoleonWilson - Making these questions work is incredibly easy and something that SFF:SE have managed with ease. Edit them to make them look nice, tag them correctly, ask the user lots of questions to try to encourage more details and delete them if the question has zero redeeming features. Note that the goal isn't for every question to be an absolute hero, but for them to be potentially answerable.

That does come back to the fundamental disagreement about the purpose of the site, though. I do know the ID questions on SFF.SE generally tend to fare a lot better with regards to post score (and possibly also answer success). However, they also basically take over the site. This isn't necessarily a jab at the site if StoryID.SE is what it wants to be (which it is allowed to want). It does, however, distort what the site is about when new users without knoweldge of the ignore feature see nothing but a wall of "what's this isekai manwha?". And thus the site's image determines its development.

Let's not lean too heavily on Jeff Atwood's stance. Over a decade ago, he made changes to Arqade against community wishes. (Sounds familiar?) The community didn't take it lying down. The community called him out in a highly upvoted meta post, saying he didn't consult them before implementing these changes. (Sounds familiar?) In the end, Jeff had to apologize.

@galacticninja If these "sounds familiar" addages are supposed to imply what I can guess they imply, I'd want to remind everyone that we actually had a proper discussion, in fact we had a ton. ;-)

@NapoleonWilson Indeed, there have been several discussions—I've counted at least 5 meta posts. And if I'm reading the votes correctly, the top-voted answers suggest the community wasn't keen on an ID ban. I think you can see where I'm going with this.

@NapoleonWilson “ID questions on SFF.SE generally tend to fare a lot better with regards to post score (and possibly also answer success). However, they also basically take over the site.” Even using SF&F as someone who doesn’t like ID questions, I haven’t found that they “basically take over the site”. There are many quality non-ID questions posted there every day.

@NapoleonWilson -> "And many users might already have left because we didn't do anything against ID until '18. It's ultimately hard to count which group is larger or would have brought more fruitful site contributions. Users come and go over all those years.": probably my time when we get this crap again though...

@OldPadawan - You can simply set the tag to 'ignore' and never see a single one, aside from those that occasionally get mis-tagged

@Valorum: as I already said -> "Closing your eyes doesn't make the dirt disappear, it hides it for you, but the stains are still here, and the others can still see it." If ignoring is an option, why don't you set your 'ignore' tag to IDQs? You ignore that they're not supported and that's it...

@NapoleonWilson - given that the consensus seems to be drifting towards accepting these questions again, we need to have a good think about how we make people asking these questions feel welcomed and valued on the site.

@Valorum I did exactly that (set the tag to ignore, here and on SFF where I am more active and has better quality IDQ), because in general I am not interested in them. However, that does not make want to see them removed entirely. I happily support IDQ even if I don't interact with them.

@Valorum Indeed. If that's the conclusion of the discussion, we all know the reality of actually bringing these questions back and making them work will be a ton of work, which is why we're having a really good think about it right now. ;-)

@OldPadawan Let's not be so quick to label ID Qs as 'dirt' and 'stains.' ID questions can be interesting and helpful to many users. The community feed is meant to serve diverse interests, not just one person's ideal. While I personally ignored the ID tag on Sci-Fi & Fantasy SE, I recognize that these questions might be both interesting and helpful to others.

It's surprising to see that the only answer with a negative score is the one that's marked as accepted. Why not let the dust settle after this post is unfeatured, then select the most-upvoted answer as the community's pick?

@galacticninja It is also strange to me that this answer is accepted since it doesn’t seem to actually answer the question, but I’m pretty sure which answer is accepted is meaningless in this situation.

@galacticninja I honestly get the impression that OP wasn't trying to start a good-faith discussion on the topic, and was instead just trying to push their own opinion on it, perhaps expecting the community to agree with them. One thing's for sure, there is a deep divide in the community regarding ID questions, and people are going to be driven away no matter what decision is taken, just as they were when ID questions were banned in the first place.

@F1Krazy Seems like a lot of the anti-ID people were here back before ID questions were banned, so maybe they'll leave if they're allowed again, but maybe they won't. It does seem like a lot of pro-ID users did leave when IDQs were banned.

tldr do what other sites have done successfully (e.g. Font ID on Graphic Design) and introduce a clear set of strict requirements for ID questions. Communicate it very clearly (Ask sidebar links, custom close reasons, tag description, standard comments...) and close anything that doesn't meet those requirements without hesitation (but allow good questions that followed the requirements, and re-open questions from good first time users who edit their questions correctly when prompted).
Bad questions from bad users disappear quickly, good questions from good users have a chance to survive and thrive. Other sites have made it work.

The problem was never identification questions, it was the high % of bad identification questions. Many sites (like Sci-Fi/Fantasy) get generally good quality ID questions and love them, many (like, I believe, Gaming) get even worse ones than we did and hate them; many sites are somewhere in between. I think there's a common pattern across the network as to whether they are good or bad:
ID questions are bad when a site's "Ask a question" form is in the Top 5 Google results for low-effort search terms like "What's the movie"
This was the case back when ID questions were at their worst: movies.SE had great search index ranking and searches like "ask what's this movie" had the Ask A Question form as the #1 result in Google. Not the homepage, not the ID tag, the actual Ask page. Click on that, and a first-time user who knows nothing about the site sees a big inviting text box they don't even need to log in to use, with very little (and very ignorable) information around it about what kind of site this even is. Of course that invites terrible-quality questions (and some good ones).
Sites like Sci-Fi and Fantasy don't have a corresponding common low-effort search string that matches their URL and h1 tags. Few lazy people are typing "what's this sci-fi and fantasy stack exchange". Therefore, their ID features tend to be used by actual SE users and tend to be higher quality. Sites like gaming rank as high as we did for "What's the game"-like searches, and struggle similarly.
This is also (as I recall, maybe I remembered wrong) why banning the questions had a seemingly slow impact on actually slowing the questions. For at least a year, the crap got deleted faster, but (to me) it didn't seem to slow down. The number of good ID questions plummeted, but the crap seemed to continue to trickle in at a similar rate. Eventually usage across the board began to slide and the site started to drop down Google rankings (for me it's now not even on the front page, well below a random ELL.SE question "Can I say: "What movie/novel is this?".
Then the questions (all types, but ID in particular) started to slow down.
Okay, but what should we actually do?
It looks like the actual cause of the underlying problem has gone away on its own. There are still some bad ID questions, but a manageable low number. It seems to make sense to cautiously allow them again, and just keep an eye on the rate (which I imagine won't change much, because it won't influence the Google ranking of the "Ask" page, and 95% of bad askers don't know or care what "on topic" means anyway and didn't hesitate to ask when they were banned).
But, to ensure quality, have very clear rules and enforce them ruthlessly.
The Graphic Design site did something similar with Font ID questions and it seemed to work; they:

created a clear set of requirements,
closed questions that didn't meet these without hesitation
re-opened questions that were edited and did meet them
had lots of time-saving boilerplate like a custom close reason that stated clearly what was required, a checklist on the tag, etc
had a clear meta post to link to outlining the requirements in more detail, and linked to it in the Ask page side bar:


This way, the amount of admin for a system that allowed good questions and purges bad ones became very similar as the amount of admin for banning all of them. For the people who didn't like them, "Hit close and copy-paste a comment" turned into "Glance to see if it meets the criteria, if yes ignore it, if no, hit close and copy-paste a comment".

That is a very interesting point with the search hits. I've never seen this brought up before. However, I have to contradict in one point: "This is also why banning the questions had such a frustratingly [...] slow impact on actually slowing the questions" I made a very different observation there. In fact I was genuinely surprised how quickly the daily influx of these questions actually drained and thought we'd still get a ton of them for quite a while. Sure, we still got the occasional one, we do now too. But we quickly went from multiple a day to few a week, and not just after a year.

It'd be interesting to see some numbers on that (though I don't know if stats are kept for deleted questions and many questions will have been roomba-ed). I wonder to what extend the number asked dropped quickly and to what extend the number seen dropped because they got closed and deleted so much faster.

Regarding the requirements, we did do things like that. Tag warnings, detail lists, closing for lack of detail (including the "ruthlessness" ;-)). Maybe we never did it rigorously enough, but it's hard to pin an objective measure to "lack of detail". E.g. does it need a year if it has an actor instead? Then get everyone to agree to these "guidelines" and actually close the crap.

Oh, there was an advisory tag popup, wasn't there? Improve and extend the automatic tag-popup for identification questions - but if I remember right there weren't hard requirements (and the whole tag got banned while that approach was being iterated on).

IIRC one thing that really helped with Font ID on Graphic Design was a hard requirement on "what automatic tools you've tried", you could see at a glance if someone had read the requirements or not. Hard requirements on "language" and "when did you see it" (since "when was it made" isn't always possible) would make it instantly obvious who read the guide and who didn't.

I can get behind this. Granted a set of "guidelines" that will have a consensus from both sides of the for/anti debate will be tough. Certainly such a guide has been proposed before (during other on/off topic debates) and did not gain much traction but I have hopes now. Lowering the close vote number to 3 so we can close "bad" questions (whether IDQ or not) would be a welcome step up too.

Also, just so I'm clear in my own mind, we're only talking [tag: identify-this-movie] right? At least for now! ☺

It deserves its own thread, but I think, make the old guidelines stricter on trying,  but with wiggle room on genuinely fuzzy memory; understanding that most ID questions will go on hold at first, 10% will be re-opened after they add details, and that's okay. e.g. must have 1) Language or country of origin (attempts like "I watched it dubbed into Flemmish but I think it was American" are okay, the important thing is, we see they bothered to try), and 2) Approx year of release (if unsure, when and where they saw it), and 3) Describe at least one scene, and 4) Describe at least one character

@Paulie_D - For me the main problem was that the increasingly tough requirements were merely a stick with which to beat ID questions. First, you make them almost impossible to ask, then you delete them en masse, then you point out how many "needed" to be deleted as evidence of them being a nuisance.

@user56reinstatemonica8 - I disagree entirely with this approach. We have made them work on SFF:SE by setting the bar quite low. As long as they are uniquely identifiable, they can stay. If you start demanding that OP keeps coming back to add extra details, these questions (which are by and large answerable) are just going to end up closed and deleted.

I'm on board with establishing clear guidelines for ID questions, including a minimum set of required details. We can always refine these as we go. I'm also not a fan of vague ID questions. Adding info to the "Ask Question" modal is a great idea, and we can refine it once the policy is in place. A tag warning for ID tags would also be helpful. My only concern is that users who strongly dislike ID questions might interpret the guidelines too rigidly, potentially closing decent, well-formulated ID questions unnecessarily. Let's aim for a balanced approach!

Thank you for bringing up the apparent success of ID questions on Sci Fi, along with logical reasons why there would be a difference.

1/2 - You use the font identification example to say it's a good (better?) way to handle such IDQ. Now, from the first (and following) page of results, almost all of them are (sub)par, with 0 vote (or worse). Very very few have an upvote, many have one answer (of course, TBH, there's only one font). That would be the same here, with even less quality, because if a font ID is useful to others, movie ID is only good for one, the one missing the title. We still would have 1 IDQ useful for only 1 person.

2/2 - Now, as for the set of requirements, we would need much more than what is actually, some kind of "I saw that movie when I was a teenager, I remember that part of a scene with a woman falling on her knees, and a knife full of blood. It's probably a movie from the 80's...".  And no more than that... Then you ask and wait for improvement. If the asker isn't gone by then because you didn't serve him an immediate answer. As their memories are somehow deficient, I fear we'll end up with poor quality data, poorly received questions but for a few...

Ah, it looks like GD:SE are no longer strict with their font ID requirements, it's been a while since did design work and was active there. It looks like they also get fewer Qs now, so I guess they decided the low numbers no longer justified the strictness. As for the "only good for one" myth, we discussed and debunked that in another thread: even in the sorted by newest view, there are several with >1000 views and over a dozen with multiple upvotes; and if you sort by top, you'll find plenty with >10k views.

Regarding "stick with which to beat ID questions"... obviously to some extent that ship has already sailed (and sunk, and took much of the site's userbase down with it). TBH I think a major part of the reason the strict approach seemed to work well where it was adopted was by giving grumpy users an outlet. They could satisfy themselves by slamming the close button, then move on, causing less damage than usual because the asker got clear, actionable feedback. Then the asker might add those details, other users re-open and answer the question, and everyone gets what they wanted.

"[...] by giving grumpy users an outlet. They could satisfy themselves by slamming the close button, then move on, causing less damage than usual": that's looks like a not-so-nice way to "identify" people (pun intended) as ***, although users who just want to keep their standards (even when not shared) where they set them.

I think we have reached a point where we need to decide whether we accept them or we don't. And if we accept them, We need the community to take a lead on making people who ask them feel welcome. That means making anyone who makes crappy comments (or abuses the close button) aware that they're being "not nice"

@OldPadawan - You're entirely ignoring the fact that many ID questions have multiple upvotes and multiple views precisely because they are useful to more than just the person who asked them

"That means making anyone who makes crappy comments (or abuses the close button) aware that they're being "not nice"": I've always thought that SE network trusted users so that they wisely use their earned powers. This quoted sentence just sounds like 'it's my way or the highway'...

@Valorum And we are indeed currently in the process of deciding that. Though, we seem to still be quite a bit away from actually reaching a clear decision on this matter (even regardless if you employ discussion or voting oriented approach to consensus). At the moment we don't accept them, but that might very well change. In any case though, close-voting on-topic questions is never something that should be done...

...If, however, a question is an edge-case or we do end up with a close-reason for lack of detail as proposed in this answer, then that lives from people making a proper judgment and the close-system crystalizing a decsion out of these individual votes. In that case, though, calling anyone who makes use of their close-voting privileges "abusing the close button" or comments asking for more details "crappy comments", is not something that fits to how either close-votes or comments work...

...Now it's possible that's not what you meant, but nuace isn't something that comes across well when it looks like you're calling voting against your own preferences "abuse". Being nice is indeed usually the prime directive that should be strived for in interactions on this site (and not only when people ask questions you like to answer), but close votes or comments asking for clarification are not per se "not nice", regardless of the question type.

We did this, and people ignored the instructions. Like I said before: back when we allowed them, at least once a day I saw a question that didn't even have the identify-tag -- if that is too much effort, then people are not gonna follow the instructions. Also, pointing out people should follow the instructions caused acrimony. And IIRC there was evidence that people who ask ID questions are overwhelmingly fly-by-night. I don't see the point of all this effort for very little return.

@BCdotWEB - Killing those questions put a huge dent in the site's activity (to the tune of a thousand questions a year and hundreds of thousands of views) from which it's never recovered. That's the point.

@BCdotWEB If everyone always followed the instructions, there would be no need for any moderation. IMHO the fact that there will be bad ID questions isn't much of an argument against allowing them. There are and will continue to be bad questions of all kinds, and we know there will be good IDQs because there already are.

@ToddWilcox The argument is: "we won't have the same problem with ID questions if we provide stricter instructions". My argument is: better instructions are pointless when people don't follow them, and they don't since I regularly saw people who didn't even use the ID tag and instead used inappropriate tags. (I recently visited SF&F and immediately saw two ID questions on the homepage because they didn't use the ID tag.) Your comment basically confirms my stance: instructions won't solve the problem with ID question: that they're often low quality.

@BCdotWEB I think your argument is mostly sound. It suffers from being the same as most other anti-IDQ arguments in that it’s about them being “very low quality”, so it adds nothing new, and like the other arguments, it doesn’t explain what “low quality” really means and why “low quality” IDQs are a bigger problem than any other type of “low quality” question. My question about it is basically “all question types come in a range of qualities, what makes the quality range of IDQs a problem compared to the quality range of all questions?”

"Low quality" means they're sometimes bordering on unintelligible (again: not using the ID tag is a massive indicator), and/or that they're easily googleable. I recall an ID question that asked about "a movie where a mother has to choose between her two children": you could literally put the question into google and get the correct result. Often people don't even bother to do any research.

@BCdotWEB - "Easily googleable." is a great reason to downvote and a terrible reason to mark for closure. Note also that not everyone's Google results are the same, especially if you're from a foreign country. Set your VPN to "China" and ask Baidu what happened on June Fourth.

Since the community consensus is now clear, I've now requested the moderators implement the change in site policy: Please update the site policy to reflect community consensus on allowing identification questions

Yes, let's allow identification questions again.
Revitalizing our community
One glaring issue we've faced recently is the alarmingly low activity on Movies & TV SE. As noted in this meta post, user and voting engagement has taken a concerning dip. Currently, we're averaging a mere 1.9 questions per day, which is worryingly low for a Stack Exchange site. SE sites with comparable or even smaller user bases have seen significantly higher participation levels.
Graph showing the number of questions per year on Movies & TV SE:

You'll notice a steep decline in posts in 2018, which is when identification questions were banned. It's no coincidence that several of our top members (by rep) left around the same time as well. This predates the more recent events involving Monica and generative AI that led to an exodus of users from Stack Exchange sites in general.
Graph source: Valorum's post at "Why does Movies Stack Exchange have low activity even on very popular titles?"
Fewer questions inevitably lead to fewer answers and less participation, creating a vicious cycle that can turn our community into a ghost town (if it isn't already). Allowing identification questions once more could be the spark we need to reignite interest and attract new enthusiastic users to our site.
Ensuring quality through curation (voting)
Some have raised concerns about the quality of identification questions, but this argument seems outdated (we last allowed ID questions more than 6 years ago) and cherry-picked, disregarding the numerous high-quality, well-written, and interesting examples we still have, such as those listed here:

https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identify-this-movie?tab=Votes
https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identify-this-tv-show?tab=Votes

Just like any other type of question, there will always be good and bad examples. However, we have the power to curate these questions through our voting system. Vague or unclear identification questions can still be closed as "needs details or clarity," just as we do with other questions.
Respecting the community's voice
Perhaps most importantly, the majority of our community has historically been against attempts to ban identification questions. As evident in the vote tallies of the answers from our previous meta discussions about ID questions (1. Discussion on identification questions, 2. Shall we ban identification questions?, 3. Check in on Identification questions, and 4. We are discontinuing support for identification questions), the community has consistently and overwhelmingly voted against any suggestion to ban them. This is now at least the fifth meta discussion post on the topic, and it will likely be the fifth time showing that the community does not support the ID ban. (Related meta post: Why are ID questions banned when there are only 55 votes in favor of it and 135 votes against it?)
The onus is on those in favor of the ban to provide evidence of a clear, current community consensus for their position. As far as I can see, there is currently no meta post showing that a clear majority of the community supports banning identification questions.
Given this long-standing lack of community support for the ID question ban, as expressed repeatedly in several meta posts, it's perplexing why the ban still remains in place. It makes one wonder if revisiting this topic through yet another meta post is truly necessary.
A way forward
Bringing back identification questions could prove immensely valuable for reinvigorating our community. It is likely to boost engagement and attract new users. We already have the means to curate these questions and ensure quality. More importantly, continuing to ban them would go against the community's wishes, as expressed repeatedly in past discussions. Let's embrace this opportunity to revitalize our community and continue providing a welcoming space for all movie and TV enthusiasts.

Wait.  Am I going mad?  Did you link to a meta post showing Ankit in favor of ID questions? lol

@steelersquirrel Yes, apparently, he was in favor of ID questions and made a lot of good points against banning ID questions, and the community agrees—their answer is the top-voted answer. :)

I see this "we have the power to curate these questions through our voting system. Vague or unclear identification questions can still be closed as "needs details or clarity," just as we do with other questions." and have to say that as a general rule... we don't. Questions with these issues (and others) aren't closed fast enough. There isn't enough DV/CV going on to weed out the trash as it is and adding to the sheer volume of the crap won't help. A 3 vote close would help but I'd rather not deal with the stuff in the first place.

@Paulie_D - I don't think the key to making ID questions work is heavy-handed closure., especially if it's based on one person's opinion that a question is "trash". I think we all need to be clear on what the absolute minimum standards are, and if those are met, the question gets to stay and we have to bite our tongues.

Sure, but whenever we tried to impose minimum standard (or even define them) we got nowhere. If you can come up with a set of standards that have a consensus I'd be overjoyed provided the "community" is willing to impose those standards on the questions we'll get. I don't oppose ID question in principle it's poor questions I objected to have to deal with and the majority of IDQ were poor, at best.

I'm not suggesting anything "heavy handed" but some additional "handedness" is required already... we don't have enough of it. I see many OT questions that linger for days because no-one is DV/CV fast enough.  And it's probably worth repeating that CV is not the same as deleting. A closed question is there to be improved.

@Paulie_D - The problem is that the minimum standards were designed to close as many questions as possible, not to find an absolute bottom limit in order to keep the reasonable ones open. If we allow these questions back, we need to be generous with the people who are asking them.

"find an absolute bottom limit in order to keep the reasonable ones open": that's the problem. Lowering the threshold to get more. Lowering the quality to get the quantity. Lowering the quality to have more fun. To get more rep. That's not what we should aim for... Better one suit from Savile Row than a full wardrobe of Shein.

@steelersquirrel When I was new I felt ID are an asset but with time and observation I felt I was wrong. Experiences change our opinions and we grow with them. For the later post I added yes just for the sake of equal chance not because I agree with it.

@OldPadawan Most of your points make sense but I don’t understand the one about not having more fun. Why not have more fun? What is this stack for if not fun? It’s not like professional movie critics are coming here to get better at their jobs.

@ToddWilcox: it's having fun in the sense of 'laughing' opposed to 'having pleasure'. They're not the same. We'd like to build a 'library of knowledge', and in a library, you can have some (silent) pleasure, not crack jokes to have fun. Just speaking for myself (with the hope that others feel the same) I take a lot of silent pleasure answering questions, because I think they're important for the library. IDQs are just some kind of instant fun before going back to 'real studies', they may help steam off the pressure, but won't help the building of the library because they help one.

@OldPadawan Huh. I think I get it. Sounds like it might be a British English vs American English thing.

@OldPadawan - I've lost track of the number of users who've posted a comment on an ID question thanking me because I've helped another user to find it. These answered questions serve as a useful signpost for people other than the original asker.

Yeah people often play the "repository of knowledge" card without even bothering to look at the stats. There are dozens, maybe even >100 ID questions with thousands of views each, and several with >10,000, as people remember and search on similar details to the original asker (some also get very few, sure, that's always the way with any set of content, a long tail of niche content does no harm)

I've been looking for numbers related to our discussion and found some interesting topics, such as this one on anime.SE.  I'd possibly go and vote for IDQ (just kiddin' ^^) if were I able to get this query adapted and work for M&TV :D but it's far beyond my SQL skills...

@OldPadawan There are old SEDE queries in this discussion that you might be able to adapt. I think I mentioned that I'm unsure if the old (deleted) IDQ will show up in a new SEDE query after the "purge" but I hope it helps.

@OldPadawan "IDQs ... won't help the building of the library because they help one." I'm curious how we know ID questions only help the asker. Depending on what we think is "help", I'd say ID questions I didn't ask have helped me before. Also, part of my brain is saying I've seen comments on an IDQ before saying something about how others have also been looking for the same thing and now they have their answer.

The review for this policy comes a little too late. Hardly any user that had his/her question banned will ever return to ask anything.
More importantly, such questions can be instantly answered by relatively decent AI models like GPT 4. This of course excludes Copilot, which has no problem at all giving wrong answers most of the time.
We all know the idea behind this is to get more traffic, the staff should have reconsidered the no-ID questions policy much earlier to begin with.

ChatGPT is appalling at answering ID questions. In fact, it's downright unhelpful due to its tendency to hallucinate plausible-sounding answers based on the prompt.

And yes, this is definitely something that's happening too late, but in the absence of any other effort to gain additional site engagement, what's the harm in trying? The alternative is that we continue to decline.
